# Trouble with regex / preg_match / str_replace with complicated string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, str-replace

I am having trouble with a complicated regex.  I have tried this every way I can think of, and I can always only get "almost" there --

I have a block of 5 messages:

```
---Agent 1: Wednesday 08/16/2017 | 11:43 AM ---

Message 1

--- Agent 1: Friday 06/09/2017 | 9:02 AM ---

Message 2

--- Agent 1: Friday 04/14/2017 | 10:35 AM ---

Message 3

--- Agent 1: Monday 02/13/2017 | 12:07 AM ---

This

is

message

3

 --- Agent 1: Monday 12/19/2016 | 1:31 PM ---

 Message 4 

 --- Agent 1: Monday 10/24/2016 | 10:48 AM ---

 Message 5
```

One problem is that some of them have a space before the first `---`.  Another is multi-line messages.

What I am trying to do is peel out all the individual messages.  Basically everything between the first occurrence of `---` and every other occurrence thereafter.  I would like my **result** to look like:

```
---Agent 1: Wednesday 08/16/2017 | 11:43 AM ---

Message 1
```

I have tried variations of `---.*? (---)` (matching every other `---`) But then I have no way of parsing out the message itself.  I have also tried to manually do this:

```
(?<=\: )(.*?)(?= \|)|(\---)(\r\n|\r|\n)(\r\n|\r|\n)(.*?)(\r\n|\r|\n)(\r\n|\r|\n)(\---)
```

Which works until you have a multi-line message. (message 3)

I have also tried multiple steps -- `trimming` the first or last `---` using `str_replace` but this is foiled by the ones that have a preceding space!

It's always the second `---` after the *time*, the multi-line message, or the preceding space *before* `---` that trips me up.  Does anyone have a more elegant solution than the monstrosity I am creating?

Comment: Where are the messages coming from? A text file / xml file / stream? Can be usefull to know

Comment: Great question @icecub  -- They are coming straight out of a `mySQL` table ... the table type is `TEXT()`

Comment: `-{3}.*[\s\S]*?(?=\s*(?:-{3}|$))`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iz0d3N/2 or so - https://regex101.com/r/iz0d3N/3

Comment: @splash That latest one with the look ahead works great!  Please post an answer with simple description and I'll gladly accept!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. I thought you only wanted the messages. My bad :)

Comment: @Zak Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/---.*---\s*\R.*(?=---|$)/gsU
```

`---.*---\s*\R` - selects the 1st line with message description. Than `.*(?=---|$)` gets the rest of a message up to start of the next one (---) or the end of the string.

[**Demo and a little explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/iz0d3N/3)

Comment: `-{3}.*-{3}\s*\R.*(?=-{3}|$)` uses fewer steps. Also `-{3}.*-{3}\s.*(?=\s*-{3}|$)` gets rid of trailing whitespace.

Comment: Yes. you're right. But I'm not sure that this will greatly affect performance. Plus, OP can easily make that replacement.

Comment: Depends on amount of data, but yes. I was just adding as a comment so that the OP could choose which method works best. Nice approach +1

Answer (score 2):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/qiqsDz/1)

```
-{3}.*[\s\S]*?(?=\s*(?:-{3}|$))
```

---

### Explanation

- `-{3}` Match a hyphen exactly 3 times
- `.*` Match any character any number of times (greedy)
- `[\s\S]*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible (lazy)
- `(?=\s*(?:-{3}|$))` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
  - `(?:-{3}|$)` Match either of the following

    - `-{3}` Match a hyphen exactly 3 times
    - `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: This is a great solution -- I accepted @splash's answer as it was slightly more elegant.  props though!  +!

Comment: @Zak no problem. This may help someone else :)